# How to deal with NSNull in my data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsnull

I am getting an `[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]:` exception when attempting to display a label.  The error reads

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]:

Below is my code.

```
UILabel* spousename = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,line, 300,20)];

[spousename setText:[_thisburial objectForKey:@"Spouse"]];
```

I tried to test for a null character with the following code but that didn't catch the error. It blew up when trying to execute the addSuview instruction.

```
if(![spousename isEqual:nil])
{
    [self.view addSubview:spousename];
}
```

So how do I test for `NSNull` in a label so I can prevent from getting this `[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]:` error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data doesn't actually have a real value for "spouse" and this has been indicated by storing an instance of `NSNull` as the value. You need to check for this.

This line:

```
[spousename setText:[_thisburial objectForKey:@"Spouse"]];
```

Should be updated to check the value. Something like this:

```
id spouse = _thisburial[@"Spouse"];
if ([spouse isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    spousename.text = spouse;
} else {
    // The "spouse" value wasn't set or it's not a string
    spousename.text = @""; // Set to whatever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[_thisburial objectForKey:@"Spouse"]` is returning an `NSNull`. There needs to be special handing for this.

```
NSString *spouseString = [_thisburial objectForKey:@"Spouse"];
if (spouseString == (id)[NSNull null]) {
    spouseString = @"";
}

[spousename setText:spouseString];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had to use if ([spouseString isEqual: [NSNull null]]) and that worked.

Comment: Sorry!  The spouseString == [NSNull null] didn't work!   It didn't recognize the null.

Comment: I tested your suggestion again using f ([spouseString.text isEqual: [NSNull null]]) and that worked also.  The key problem was that I wasn't using the text suffix on the variable.

Comment: @Dave that odd `spouseString.text` should crash. Neither `NSString` nor `NSNull` has a property `text`.

Comment: It really doesn't matter. @rmaddy has a better answer.